# RaspBerry Pi3: Trying to put a lua file in lutro (recalbox) not working

Tags: lua, raspberry-pi

I'm currently trying to run a Lua file (A game developed by my class for a school project) on lutro which is in Recalbox (OS running on a raspberry pi3). After many tries, I and my group discovered that only .lutro files can be launched on lutro. However, I can't find any way to create a .lutro file or to convert a .lua file into a .lutro file. The final goal is to launch a game coded in lua on a raspberry pi3. What it does now: It runs .lutro games perfectly, but it doesn't launch Lua files, it runs the game for 2 seconds and automatically exits the game (With nothing showing up on the screen).

I would need help very soon, my group's time is running out D:

Comment: You should find some log containing the error message.

Comment: Can you give an example of .lutro file?

Comment: Pong.lutro when it is launched on recalbox it creates a folder named pong with lua files and moon files. I have no idea how these .lutro files work... You can find some .lutro files on Lutro's website (https://www.libretro.com/index.php/lutro-easy-retro-game-creation-powered-by-libretro/) with their premade games I think.

Comment: https://github.com/libretro/libretro-lutro states "you can load a compressed .lutro file", which makes me think it's probably just like with löve, where you just zip the project folder. Try unzipping a .lutro file and see if it works; if so, just zip your project and rename it from `<name>.zip` to `<name>.lutro`

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately :/ it doesn't work.